# Analog-to-Digital-Converter and resolution

Tags: resolution

A (linear) Analog-to-Digital-Converter has a sample rate of `10k sample per sec` and a resolution of 20Bit.

```
Minimum input voltage: -2volts,
Maximum input voltage: +2volts
```

1. What is the smallest voltage-step(not equal to 0) the ADC can resolve?
2. What is the dynamic range of the ADC?

> dyn.rangedB=20*log(max.level/min.level)

Till now what I did.
I supposed -2 volts to be all 0 20 times as it has 20 bit resolution and +2 volts to be `2^20=1048575.`
So now To answer the first question I did

> 2/1048575=0.00190mV

Am I correct? and I don't the idea of dynamic range of the ADC.

Comment: Before, I thought people were being harsh... But I can see their annoyance with posts like these. This is obviously a homework question, so if you want help, at least show us what you have done so far, and what particular area you are having issues with.

Comment: I ask forgiveness for my blunder. But I could not grasp the idea of ADC. Any help would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked several questions now and every time it has been nearly a direct request for others to do your homework. You appear to have made a marginal attempt at this one so I will help you along.

Your attempt is somewhat correct, but you have not considered the entire range the ADC can work with. This problem is really quite simple if you understand what *resolution* means in this context; a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=adc%20resolution&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl) gives a nice definition.

You appear to be on the right path since you realized that 20 bits of resolution means you have `2^20` discrete *slots*, if you will, that the input can be digitized to.

Your solution will have units `volt/slot`, where *slot* is a discrete state, so with with a bit of dimensional analysis ..

Comment: I can still find the answer without the sampling rate. Why do I need sampling rate here?

Comment: @Lifestohack, it appears to be excess information. The sampling rate gives you information pertaining to the frequencies that it may confidently report for. If you, for example, are trying to sample a sinusoid that has a frequency of 10Khz then of course you will never be able to reconstruct that signal.

Comment: To add to sherrellbc's answer, keep in mind that (to my knowledge) you usually have to bias an AC signal to DC. That is, you are shifting -2 volts in this case to 0 volts, and thus you are shifting 2 volts to 4 volts. Or if you want the voltage range of the AC, look at the range from peak to peak voltage.