# How to find the dynamic range of ADC?

Tags: adc

I bought a Analog to Digital Converter but did not gave much attention to Dynamic range. The resolution is 12 Bit. Minimum input voltage is 0V and maximum is 5V.

The problem is I don't have the datasheet and want to know how can I find the Dynamic range of this ADC?

Additional info: It says it has 10Megasample per sec of sample-rate.

Comment: Given the part number you can easily find the datasheet, which will answer the question.

Comment: Did you mean 'I have a homework question that noone wants to answer so I try it this way'? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118457/analog-to-digital-converter-and-resolution

Comment: Regarding 1.76 db, to my understanding it comes from the factor 1/2:1/3 = 1.5 in dB. 1/2 is for calculating the signal power assuming a narrowband quasi sinusoidal signal. 1/3 is for calculating quantization noise power assuming a uniform distribution with +/-LSB/2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dynamic range is the ratio of the maximum voltage to the minimum voltage that the ADC can convert.  The maximum voltage is 5 volts.  Since it is a 12-bit converter, it has a resolution of 1 in \$2^{12}\$ or 4096. Thus the minimum voltage, for which the ADC would have only the least significant bit set, is 5V/4096 = 1.22 millivolts.  So the dynamic range of your ADC is 5/1.22mV = 4096 = 72.2 dB. In general, the dynamic range is only a function of the number of bits, not the maximum input voltage. But I calculated using voltage to show you the details.

Comment: That provides an upper limit on the dynamic range. The true figure will be lower, and depend on the actual device and the circuitry around it.

Comment: I thought that the *resolution* would be 1.22mV and the *dynamic range* is analogous to the input range - 5V. The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range) says `"[Dynamic Range is] .. the ratio between the largest and smallest possible values of a changeable quantity`".

Comment: @Barry you said it has a resolution of 2¹²-1 or 4095 but according to the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter it is just 2¹²?

Answer (score 7):

The dynamic range is the ratio (usually expressed in dB) between the noise floor of the ADC and the maximum input.

As Brian says in his comment, the *quantization* noise sets a lower limit on the noise floor at the actual sample rate, however the noise of a real ADC will be higher than the quantization noise.

Also, if you take your 10Msps ADC and band-limit and decimate the output to a lower sample rate the dynamic range can be increased, by as much as 10dB for a decade of down-sampling.

Comment: What do you mean by quantization noise and noise of the ADC? I understand what quantization is, but not its use in the context of noise. Do you mean that the dynamic range of the ADC will be impacted due to the quantization *of* noise superimposed on the signal we are attempting to digitize? (i.e. signal to sample + noise floor?)

Comment: @sherrellbc There will be some internal noise in addition to the quantization noise. The effective number of bits (ENOB) of a "24-bit" ADC might be 19 bits under certain conditions, so if you use 24 bits in the calculation you'll be overly optimistic.

Comment: I see - similar to calculating significant digits beyond the precision you know certain variables to. How much you determien the ENOF of a particular ADC? Experimentation with high-precision voltages? How exactly would you define "quantization noise"? I find very little when searching that term. From what I gather the definition seems to parallel *quantization error*, but are they exactly the same thing?

Comment: @sherrellbc ENOB is often listed in the datasheet. It's always less than the actual number of bits (because quantization noise sets a lower floor).

Answer (score 3):

THE dynamic range of your ADC is calculated as DR= 6.021*N + 1.763 dB
where N= is the number of bits i.e 12 bit
DR= 74dB.

Comment: Can you explain the constant 1.763dB here? I can understand that each new bit doubles the voltage range, so provides ~6dB of dynamic range, but not sure how a 0 bit ADC would have 1.763dB of dynamic range ;)

Comment: I found a link to a very in depth derivation here: http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-229.pdf

Comment: This is actually the signal-to-noise ratio of an ADC, the dynamic range is subtly different.